# Javascript calling method from method

Tags: javascript, oop

I am a trying to make a simple program in OOP javascript. When I try to call method2 in method1 I get the following error **this is undefined**

```
class Hell()
{
   constructor()
   {
       alert("welcome");
   }

   method1()
   {
       alert("method1");
       this.method2();
   }

   method2()
   {
       alert("method2");
   }
}
```

Shouldn't this work fine?

Comment: `class Hell()` Invalid syntax... fixing that, works just fine

Comment: @CertainPerformance Don't forget to vote to close :-)

Comment: He says `I get the following error method2 is undefined` it's sounding like it's running for him (rather than refusing to start due to a syntax error), I'm guessing he didn't paste the actual code

Comment: I am trying to understand how a method 2 can be called from method 1
In C# its pretty easy, but I believe for javascript it doesn't works this way, so what way can method2 can be called from method1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Hell{
  constructor()
  {
   alert("welcome");
  }

  method1()
  {
   alert("method1");
   this.method2();
  }

  method2()
  {
   alert("method2");
  }
}

var a = new Hell();
a.method1();
```